# PHP and WSDL 2.0 SOAP

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl

It is possible to use php with WSDL 2.0 soap webservice? I read a lot old posts, that tells me php soap doesn't support wsdl 2.0. Is there some solutions? I don't want to write webservice in php, I want get data from wsdl 2.0 service. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  SoapClient or NuSoap. SoapClient is based of C and  NuSoap in PHP

Here I am using SoapClient

```
$url_t0_wsdel = "www.example.com/wsdl"
$wsdelData = new SoapClient($url_t0_wsdel);

$result = $wsdelData->__soapCall('name_of_procedure', array(arguments));
```

$result will be array or object format

Comment: PHP SoapClient supports only WSDL 1.1. Not 2.0